# Delete reveresed rows in Matlab

Tags: matlab

**Problem**

I have an edgelist and I want to remove all inverted lines so that instead of:

```
2707    2709
2709    2707
2709    3019
```

only this remains:

```
2707    2709
2709    3019
```

**I tried:**

```
Edgelist=unique(Edgelist,'rows');
```

But it doesnt come up with the results I want. Anyone having an idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in one line of code.
First sort the matrix Row wise. Then take unique rows.

```
A = [2707, 2709;
     2709, 2707;
     2709, 3019];

unique(sort(A,2),'rows')

ans =

 2707  2709
 2709  3019
```